# linked list interview queston

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging, linked-list

So the question is:

*Given a (singly) linked list with head node root, write a function to split the linked list into k consecutive linked list "parts".

The length of each part should be as equal as possible: no two parts should have a size differing by more than 1. This may lead to some parts being null.

The parts should be in order of occurrence in the input list, and parts occurring earlier should always have a size greater than or equal parts occurring later.

Return a List of ListNode's representing the linked list parts that are formed.*

I did the thinking part and got that the first index of the ans[] should have N%k + N/k nodes and the subsequent parts of the ans array should have N/k nodes so for example:

```
     [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] k=3

     ans = [ [1,2,3,4] [5,6,7] [8,9,10] ]
```

you can see that ans[0] has length N%k + N/k = 10%3 +10/3 = 1+3=4 and the rest have N/k length = 3

But i am stuck with the implementation i tried to debug my code but i am not sure where it is wrong.

```
public ListNode[] splitListToParts(ListNode root, int k) {
    ListNode node = root;
    int N=0;
    while(node!=null){
        N++;
        node = node.next;
    }

    int intervalLen = N/k;
    int start = N%k;

    ListNode[] ans = new ListNode[k];
    ListNode temp = root;
    for(int z=0; z<start; z++){
        System.out.println(temp.val);
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    ans[0] = root;
    ListNode nextNode = temp;
    ListNode currNode = temp;
    ListNode hold = root;
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
        if(i==0){
            hold = root;
        }else{
            hold = nextNode;
        }
        for(int j=0; j<intervalLen-1;j++){
            System.out.println(temp.val);
            temp=temp.next;
        }
        nextNode = temp.next;//error here
        currNode = temp;
        currNode.next = null;
        temp = nextNode;
        ans[i] = hold;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

when i try to print it gives me null pointer exception at 4 with sys out i get this as output

```
  1, 2, 3, 4... error
```

so i am guessing that the 4 is pointing to null and that on the next loop we try to do nextNode = temp.next...nextNode=null.next which gives the error.. but i have made sure in the code to have next pointer curr pointer to avoid this but it still happens i am not sure why i am getting an error.

Comment: sorry but, 4.next must point to null,no?

Answer (score 0):

i was thinking about something like this (explanation as comment on the code);

```java
public ListNode[] splitListToParts(ListNode root, int k) {
    ListNode node = root;
    int N=0;
    while(node!=null){
        N++;
        node = node.next;
    }
    int intervalLen = N/k;
    int start = N%k;
    ListNode[] ans = new ListNode[k];
    ListNode curr = root; // curr = current first element
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
        ans[i] = curr; // saving the current first element in the array
        int elements = N / k; // elements is the number of elements to have in that array
        /*
        if the module give a number below the current element, increase elements.
        let's take the example, + 1
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] k=3
        the answer is 
        [1->2->3->4 , 5->6->7->8 , 9->10->11] right? so the module will return 11%3 = 2
        and infact the 1st (index 0) and the 2nd (index 1) will have a + 1 element, and infact if 
        i < 2 we are working on the first (index 0) or in the second (index 1)
        */
        if(N%k < i) elements++; 
        for(int j=0; j<elements;j++){ // just cicling on the values
            System.out.println(temp.val);
            curr=curr.next; // moving the current element to the next
        }
        ListNode tmp = curr; // saving the current element to a tmp variable
        curr = curr.next; // moving the current one in order to have the right element at the beginning of the next cicle
        tmp.next = NULL; // remove the pointer from the last element of this list to the first element of the next
    }
    return ans
}
```